# How do I create a real Python server with a real IP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, tcp, client

Currently, I have developed a Chat Python app using sockets. I have the `Server.py` and `Client.py` clients. I get it to work on the localhost (127.0.0.1) but I want to take a step further and I want to be able to run a real server and have friends connect to it from their homes.

How would I do that? How do I establish the server with a real IP?

I tried to find a similar question but I wasn't able to.

Comment: What you should see is how to deploy your application. I have no experience deploying plain python projects but django projects so I can recommend you [this site](https://www.fullstackpython.com/deployment.html) to accomplish your task. Good look!

Comment: You can also take a look at [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction) or [OVH VPS](https://www.ovh.com/world/vps/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to get hosting and move the chatbot files to the server. Consider [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com) as python backends to deploy the chatbot.

**A few steps here:**

**1)** Get some form of hosting. Two good cheap solutions for developers are

1. www.digitalocean.com
2. www.linode.com

   For digital ocean you can get away for 5$ a month. Linode I think is 10$ a 
   month.

**2)** Download python and your chatbot's required modules onto the server.

**3)** FTP your chatbot files onto the server and deploy with your framework of choice.

**4)** Register a domain (optional), ie https://eduardobot.com

**5)** Point the dns of your domain name to the ip of the server hosting your website.

## Assuming you get an Ubuntu 14.04 server with Digital Ocean, the steps would be as follows

Register an Ubuntu-14.04 droplet, which will send an email containing a temporary password for the Ubuntu server

**Open your terminal/command line and enter:**

```
ssh root@server-ip-address
```

This will prompt you to enter a password. Now enter the password that Digital Ocean emailed to you. This will allow you to set a new password. After you've made your own, you'll be logged into the digital ocean server via ssh from your terminal.

**Now enter the following commands:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

Once this is complete, Python 3 will be installed to the server. **Confirm this by running:**

```
python3 -V
```

**Now install pip to the Ubuntu server**

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
```

**Install your chatbot's dependencies**

```
pip3 install Flask
pip3 install nltk
pip3 install spacy
pip3 install re
pip3 install time
...
```

To make sure the development environment is sufficient:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

Now upload your chatbot files to your server. The easiest way to do this would is via FTP, like [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org) or [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io)

Once the app was successfully running on the server, you could have your friends find the bot by the servers ip address.

If you wanted a domain name,  you would just have to go into the domain's DNS after purchasing and change the nameservers to

```
ns1.digitalocean.com
ns2.digitalocean.com
ns3.digitalocean.com
```

Depending on the domain provider, you may have to provide A, cname, or other DNS records.

I'm not trying to plug digital ocean, I just use it because it's cheap. You could accomplish the same thing with any good hosting provider.